# How to use the Edit button in eclipse for a plugin eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have integrated a menu to the eclipse toolbar to create an editor. I would like to link the button in the Edit menu of eclipse (which allows to copy, paste, cut, delete ...), to the methods I use in my Editor.

For example, my editor creates a canvas in which I can draw. I would like to use the button "copy" in the Edit eclipse menu to copy my draw. The method is already implemented (on the picture, you can see the "copy" button which works), I just need to make the link between the Edit eclipse menu and my method.
[image]
How can I do that ?

If I am not clear enough, tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the editor action bar contributor class that you specify in the `org.eclipse.ui.editors` extension point to do this

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.editors"> 
  <editor 
     id="com.xyz.Editor" 
     contributorClass="com.xyz.EditorContributor" 
     ...more ....> 
  </editor> 
</extension>
```

Your contributor class will normally extend `org.eclipse.ui.part.EditorActionBarContributor`. For a text editor or a mult-page editor there are other contributor classes you can extend.

You override the `setActiveEditor` method to be told when your editor becomes active. When your editor is active you set the global action handler for the global actions you want to handle, something like:

```
public class EditorContributor extends EditorActionBarContributor
{
  private IEditorPart activeEditorPart = null;

  @Override
  public void setActiveEditor(IEditorPart targetEditor)
  {
    if (activeEditorPart == targetEditor)
      return;

    activeEditorPart = targetEditor;

    if (targetEditor instanceof MyEditor) {
        IActionBars actionBars = getActionBars();

        actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(ActionFactory.COPY.getId(), copyAction);
        // ... more global action handlers
    }
  }
}
```

where `copyAction` is an `Action` that you write.

You can also override the `contributeToToolBar` and `contributeToMenu` methods to add new actions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When do I have to instantiate this class ? On start ?
I don't know how to link my copy  method to the copyAction (I know that I must declare an Action action = new Action (), but how to set copy after that ?)

Comment: Eclipse creates this class for you using the information in the extension point.

Comment: Otherwise, do you think it is possible to use directly the functions cut, copy, paste, delete, select all of the "Edit" menu ? I think these functionalities do the same things that the ones I implemented. The only difference is that it would be applied not on text, but on a different object.

Comment: No, you have to write your own copy etc. and hook it up like this.

Comment: Alright, thanks. My problem now is that my copyAction is a void method. I do not know how to declare it as a IAction. Any Idea ?

Comment: You have to write a Class which implements IAction (or more usually extends Action). The `run` method of the action class can call other methods in your editor.